# How to update parent column if all child column has same data using trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table name 'sys_parent' like below

```
  |-----|------|--------|
  | id  | name | status |
  |-----|------|--------|
  | 101 | bi   |   n    |
```

And another table 'sys_child' like below

```
   |-----|-----------|--------|--------|
   | id  | parent_id | name   | status |
   |-----|-----------|--------|--------|
   | 1   |     101   |   b    |   n    |
   | 2   |     101   |   c    |   n    |
   | 3   |     101   |   d    |   y    |
```

where sys_child.`parent_id` is foreign key of sys_parent.`id`
The question is if I updated every status of sys_child to 'n' then the parent sys_parent.`status` will update to 'n' and vice-versa. I have tried

```
  DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER new_trigger 
    AFTER UPDATE ON sys_child
       FOR EACH ROW 
            BEGIN
             SET @changetype = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys_child GROUP BY `status`);
             SET @statustype = (SELECT `status` FROM sys_child GROUP BY `status`);
                     IF @changetype < 2
                            THEN UPDATE sys_parent
                                SET  `status`= @statustype;
                        END IF;
  END$$
 DELIMITER;
```

But it doesnot work. How can I achieve this using mysql trigger ??

Comment: I think this is because, you arr trying to store more than one value into the two variables. The 'select count(*)... group by status' will give out two rows - the count of 'n' and the count of 'y'. So, the variable @changetype is not SET here.. The same happens with status type..

Comment: @Krishnakumar So how can it be done then ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trigger will do what you want. On an update, it finds out how many children the parent of the current child has (`num_children`), then it finds out how many of those children have the same status as the current child (`this_status`). If these values are the same, then all children have the same status, and the parent is updated with that value.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER new_trigger 
  AFTER UPDATE ON sys_child
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE num_children, this_status INT;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num_children FROM sys_child WHERE parent_id = NEW.parent_id;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO this_status FROM sys_child WHERE parent_id = NEW.parent_id AND status = NEW.status;
        IF num_children = this_status THEN
            UPDATE sys_parent SET status= NEW.status;
        END IF;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you soo much.

Comment: You are awesome dude. Can u point me best website to learn advanced mysql  ??